# Prisma Many-to-Many Relation

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, prisma

```
model Students {
  studentId Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  user      User?    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
  userId    Int?     @unique
  classCode String?
  courses   Course[]
}

model Course {
  courseId          Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  courseName        String
  courseDescription String?
  courseInstructor  String
  classes           Classes[]
  students          Students[]
}
```

I have data in both tables seperately. I do not want to insert data in one and connect it to other using implicit relation. I just want to connect them in their implicit model by inserting both foreign key in that table by create or insert query using prisma.

for now their implicit created model is empty.

I want to know the query for that in prisma client.

I have made the relations between two models of many to many. I have data in both tables separately and their implicit model in empty. I just want to add the foreign in that table by myself to connect them. I want to know the query for that in prisma client.

Comment: Based on your use case, if you want to insert data directly into the connecting table then you should consider using explicit many to many relation. The implicit table which is directly managed by Prisma is not surfaced in the schema file as mentioned in the docs here: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/many-to-many-relations#implicit-many-to-many-relations

Comment: thank @NurulSundarani we can also insert the data directly into into implicit table as well.... I was just using the wrong foreign key which was not existing...! appreciate your answer.... thanks again

Comment: Yes you can directly add data in implicit table as it exists in the database, it's just that it's not surfaced in schema file. I am glad to hear that you were able to solve the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is `connect` and `create`. based on prisma documantation you can create query like this.

To connect a student and many course :

```
await prisma.student.create({
  data: {
    userId: 1,
    classCode: "2"
    Course: { connect: [{ courseName: 'programming', courseDescription: "desc", courseInstructor: "Mr/Mrs" }, { courseName: 'development', courseDescription: "desc", courseInstructor: "Mr/Mrs" }] },
  },
})
```

To create a student and many course :

```
await prisma.student.create({
  data: {
    userId: 1,
    classCode: "2"
    Course: { connect: [{ courseName: 'programming', courseDescription: "desc", courseInstructor: "Mr/Mrs" }, { courseName: 'development', courseDescription: "desc", courseInstructor: "Mr/Mrs" }] },
  },
})
```

or you can use `connectOrCreate`

Reference : https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/troubleshooting-orm/help-articles/working-with-many-to-many-relations

Comment: appreciate your answer .... the problem was solved. Thank you